# Question about AMD cpu and if there are any problems with any particular libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting a new laptop, the best laptop (or at least on paper) that I saw is using amd cpu and gpu. I heard that amd doesn't work well with tensorflow, curious if this is true, if is true is there any other important libraries in python that it doesn't work well with?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is implemented above CUDA which is an NVidia API for GPGPU (General Purpose GPU usage) that is supported by NVidia GPUs. AMD GPUs support an open standard GPGPU which was later written (OpenCL), however, they differ.

Training on large datasets without using a GPU is possible, but will take much longer.

There seem to be various **unofficial** solutions (e.g. [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337313/does-tensorflow-plan-to-support-opencl), [ref2](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/use-amd-gpu-for-model-training/2011)) to using Tensorflow with OpenCL, which could work on AMD GPUs, however, if you want this to work out of the box with the latest versions, you'll need an NVidia GPU.